# Sort array using two values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array using two values (order, sub_order) so that they are orders like 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.1.

Below is an example of the array as it is now and the second is the array sorted correctly by the order and sub_order values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order] => 1
            [sub_order] => 2
            [title] => Blah 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [order] => 2
            [sub_order] => 2
            [title] => Blah 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [order] => 1
            [sub_order] => 1
            [title] => Blah 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [order] => 2
            [sub_order] => 1
            [title] => Blah 
        )

)
```

Ordered correctly...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [order] => 1
            [sub_order] => 1
            [title] => Blah 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [order] => 1
            [sub_order] => 2
            [title] => Blah 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [order] => 2
            [sub_order] => 1
            [title] => Blah 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [order] => 2
            [sub_order] => 2
            [title] => Blah 
        )

)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried writing a [usort](http://php.net/usort) function to sort it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `usort`

```
usort($array, "order_sub_order_sort");
function order_sub_order_sort($a, $b) {
    if ($a["order"] != $b["order"]) {
        return $a["order"] - $b["order"];
    }
    return $a["sub_order"] - $b["sub_order"]
}
```

Change `$a-$b` for `$b-$a` if you want to sort the other way around. I always forget which is ascending and which is descending.

Comment: Nicely done. If `order_sub_order_sort` is one-time use, you can even just use an anonymous function as the second parameter to `usort`.

Comment: @Halcyon Thanks just the job ;)